# IE stuck at permissions request

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, permissions

I have a desktop app that was previously working. I call the FB app with: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=401292276603778&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&scope=manage_pages%2Cpublish_stream%2Cphoto_upload&response_type=token&display=popup

Recently, this has been getting stuck in IE at the permissions request page. No matter how many times I hit the "allow" button, it stays on the permissions request page. It doesn't get stuck in Firefox or Chrome. But since the desktop app uses an embedded IE browser, I'm now stuck. There's been no code changes on my end and I estimate the problem arose over the last week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We're experiencing the same issue here.

It appears to be across any site - we've tried on Vimeo.com as well as our own and we can replicate the issue on each site.

The steps we're taking to see the issue are as follows:

1. Ensure you have a Facebook account that has never been used on the
   site before
2. Ensure you are **not** logged into that Facebook account
3. Visit the website, click the Facebook login button
4. You’ll go to Facebook, log in
5. It’ll then show you a permissions screen with a button to Goto App
6. Clicking that button just results in an infinite loop where the page reloads and you see the same thing again

The issue can even be replicated on Facebook's own page on the developer site - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

Comment: It sounds like a bug on facebook. The best thing to do is report the issue at: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Hi Neil, good point. Just did a quick search and someone has logged the issue. http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/434269633305911?browse=search_50ac89c3c56095204230188 - fingers crossed for a quick resolution!

Comment: There seems to be a lot of people having this issue so I'd imagine it should be a quick turnaround.